# Android - In-app billing almost working?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I followed this guide: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html

I created a test account and bought an item from myself, and it worked. The item costs 9SEK (swedish), but it was drawn twice, one for 8SEK (what's this?) and the other for 9SEK (item I guess?). I also received twice the nonce JSONObject which gives the information about the purchase. Then I received a mail from Google Play saying that i bought this item, but haven't received any mail to my original account saying that an item was bought. Anyone have a clue why this happened?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I just logged in to my account and I can see that one item was selled for 9SEK, so that's okey. But where did the 8SEK come from?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming issue really, more of a Google Play support issue.

Comment: Alright, I'll send them a mail and see what they say, thanks!